# Can "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" cause server crash?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have been doing research over SO about the exception

```
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I know basically it may caused by calling `getWriter()` and `getOutputStream()` for one `HttpServletResponse`, as mix text and other MIME type together to return to client.

However, I am not sure if this exception occurs, and if occurs repeatingly, can cause server crash? (as the data in the buffer by `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` become ghost)?

Comment: Usual cause is trying to call getOutputStream() in a JSP after having printed something, even whitespace. Just use an explicit servlet instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) that's a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

> `RuntimeException` is a [unchecked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) exception that will not cause the system/server crash at all.

---

#### How to avoid IllegalStateException in java servlet?

The root cause of `IllegalStateException` exception is a java servlet is attempting to write to the output stream (response) after the response has been committed.

It is always better to ensure that no content is added to the response after the forward or redirect is done to avoid `IllegalStateException`. It can be done by including a `return` statement immediately next to the forward or redirect statement.

---

For more solutions have a look at [JSP-Servlet Q&A » Development » IllegalStateException](http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/JSP-Servlet/Development/IllegalStateException.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on the servlet container but normally exceptions inside the servlet code don't crash the whole server.

If you're worrying about a posible memory leak here it's also unlikely to happen in this case. This exception is just a contract enforcement. The servlet container tells you that you should use either getOutputStream() or getWriter() but never both during a single request.

Comment: I'd be amazed if this error triggered anything more than a stack trace in the logs and a 500 response (or a partial response if already committed) to the user agent.